# How to save input values to the DOM and not have them reset after every function

Tags: javascript

Here I have a Ecommerce Website (using for practice). The data I am inputting onto the screen is from JSON. But the issue I am having is that I have a function that adds the item to the cart. In each item that they add, they have a name, price, quantity. Well the issue is that every time the user adds an item, the input value changes back to 1, because that's the initial value I set in my inner HTML, how do set it to where the input stays the same to what the user put in. Open for criticism, here to learn!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ecommerce Website</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    
    <ul class="navbar">
        <div class="leftside">
            <li class="navitem"><a href="www.google.com">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navitem"><a href="www.google.com">Shop</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            <li><i class="far fa-shopping-bag  cart"></i></li>
            <!-- <div class="cartoverlay "> -->
            <div class="cartbody"><h1 class="exiticon">X</h1>
                <h1 class="carttitle">Your Items</h1>
                <div class="cartitems">
            <!-- <div class="cartitem"><img src="./md-salman-tWOz2_EK5EQ-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="cartitemimg"><h1 class="cartitemname">Bob</h1><h2 class="cartitemprice">3.99</h2><input type="number" value="1" class="CartInput"><button class="removecartbtn">Remove</button></div> -->
            
            
        </div>
        <h1 class="totalcartprice">$0</h1>
            </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
    </ul>

    <div class="glide">
        <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
          <ul class="glide__slides">
   
            <div class="slide1container">
            <li class="glide__slide slide1"><img class="glideimg" src="./md-salman-tWOz2_EK5EQ-unsplash.jpg" alt=""><h1 class="slidertitle slidertitle1">Come try our new items</h1>
            </li>
        </div>

            <div class="slide2container">
            <li class="glide__slide slide2"><img class="glideimg" src="./md-salman-tWOz2_EK5EQ-unsplash.jpg" alt=""><h1 class="slidertitle  slidertitle2">Slide 2</h1>
            </li>
        </div>
        
            <div class="slide3container">
            <li class="glide__slide slide3"><img class="glideimg" src="./md-salman-tWOz2_EK5EQ-unsplash.jpg" alt=""><h1 class="slidertitle slidertitle3">Slide 3</h1>
            </li>
        </div>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
            <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">prev</button>
            <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">next</button>
          </div>
      </div>



        <!-- ITEM TABS -->
        <ul class="itemtabcontainer">
            <li class="itemtab active">All</li>
            <li class="itemtab">New</li>
            <li class="itemtab">Sales</li>
            <li class="itemtab">Best</li>
        </ul>
<div class="itemscontainer">



    
</div>

</div>
</body>


<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide"></script>
<script>
    
    const config = {
        type: 'carousel',
        startAt: 0,
        perView: 1,
}
    
    new Glide('.glide', config).mount()
    
  </script>
<script src="ProductsData.json"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 1.2em;
    transition: 0.1s ease;
}
.navbar i{
    color: black;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 8vh;
}
.navbar li:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.leftside{
    display: flex;
    gap: 3em;
    transform: translateX(-10%);
}

.rightside{
    position: relative;
}
.glide{
    width: 75vw;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8vh;
}

.glide img{
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.slide{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.slidertitle{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(10vw, -50vh);
}
.cartbody{
    width: 30vw;
    background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 70%;
    transform: translateX(00%);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.cartactive{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
.cartitem{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 1em 0em;
}
.exiticon{
    font-size: 3rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.carttitle{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.cartitemname{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
.cartbody input{
    width: 30px;
}
.cartitemprice{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.cartitemimg{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
.removecartbtn{
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cartitems{
    height: 55vh;
}
.totalcartprice{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 26, 255);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em 0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
}
.itemtabcontainer{
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5vh;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}
.itemtab{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.itemtabcontainer .active{
    border-bottom: black 2px solid;

}
.itemimg{
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
}
.itemscontainer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.topitemcontainer{
    padding: 1.2em 0em;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item{
    height: 400px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 2px 5px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 3px -1px;
}

.atcbtn{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0.3em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;

}
.atcbtn:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let cart = document.querySelector('.cart')
let exiticon = document.querySelector('.exiticon')
let cartbody = document.querySelector('.cartbody')
let productlist = document.querySelector('.itemscontainer')
let atcbtns = document.querySelector('.atcbtn')
let cartitem = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitem')
let cartitems = document.querySelector('.cartitems')
let removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('removecartbtn')
let CartInput = document.getElementsByClassName('CartInput')



FetchProductsData()
function FetchProductsData(){
  fetch('ProductsData.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(Product => {
        productlist.innerHTML += `<div class="item"><img src="./md-salman-tWOz2_EK5EQ-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="itemimg"><div class="topitemcontainer"><h2 class="itemname">${Product.name}</h2><h2 class="itemprice">$${Product.price}</h2></div><div class="bottomitemcontainer"><button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button></div></div>`
    });
})
.catch(error => {
  alert('user live server or local server')
})
}

productlist.addEventListener('click', AddToCart)

function AddToCart(e){
  
  if(e.target.classList.contains('atcbtn')){
    console.log('User Clicked a Button')

  let Product = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.topitemcontainer')
  let ProductImg = Product.querySelector('.itemimg')
  let ProductName  =Product.querySelector('.itemname').innerText
  let ProductPrice = Product.querySelector('.itemprice').innerText


  //HERE IS THE ISSUE, INPUT VALUE RESETS
  cartitems.innerHTML += `<div class="cartitem"><img src="./md-salman-tWOz2_EK5EQ-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="cartitemimg"><h1 class="cartitemname">${ProductName}</h1><h2 class="cartitemprice">${ProductPrice}</h2><input type="number" value="1" class="CartInput"><button class="removecartbtn">Remove</button></div>`

  console.log
  for(let i = 0; i < CartInput.length; i++){
    console.log(CartInput[i].value)

    CartInput[i].addEventListener('change', GetCartInputs)
  }
  console.log('item added!')
  GetTotalPrice()
}


for(let i = 0; i < removebtn.length; i++){
  removebtn[i].addEventListener('click', removeItem)
}
}


function GetCartInputs(e){
  let CartInput = document.querySelector('.CartInput')
  let NewCartInput = e.target
  console.log(CartInput)
  console.log(NewCartInput)


  //MAKE SURE THE USER PUTS IN A VALID VALUE
  if(isNaN(NewCartInput.value) || NewCartInput.value <= 0){
  NewCartInput.value = 1
  }  



  
  GetTotalPrice()
}

function GetTotalPrice(){
  let total = 0
  let TotalPrice = document.querySelector('.totalcartprice')
  let PriceFields = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitemprice')
  let Inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('CartInput')
  // console.log(Inputs)
  

    for(let i = 0; i < PriceFields.length; i++){
      // console.log(PriceFields.length)
      let AllPrices = Number(PriceFields[i].innerText.replace('$', ''))
      let AllInputs = Inputs[i].value
      total += AllPrices * AllInputs
      TotalPrice.innerText = ('$' + total.toFixed(2))
    }
}





function removeItem(e){
  let TotalPrice = document.querySelector('.totalcartprice')
  del_btn = e.target
  del_btn_parent = del_btn.parentElement
  del_btn_parent.remove()
  if(removebtn.length === 0){
    TotalPrice.innerHTML = '$' + 0
  }
  GetTotalPrice()

}
```

JSON FILE WITH DATA

```
[
    

        {
            "name": "Shoes", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 12.99,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "T shirt", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 7.99,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Necklace", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 2.99,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Pants", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 4.99,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Hat", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 12,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Socks", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 12,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Glasses", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 12,
            "image": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Ring", 
            "category": 12,
            "price": 12,
            "image": 12
        }

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cartItems.append(yourItem)` or `cartItems.prepend(yourItem)` instead of `.innerHTML`

innerHTML wipes out previous items... so you're replacing not persisting

Comment: Thank You. That makes a whole lot more sense

Comment: consider accepting my answer if it solved your issue...